# How to set profile to QQmlApplicationEngine?

Tags: python, pyqt, qml, pyqt5, qqmlapplicationengine

I want to web profile to QQmlApplicationEngine like this QWebEngine code:

```
web = QWebEngineView()
pf = QWebEngineProfile("unsurf", web)
page = QWebEnginePage(pf, web)
web.setPage(page)
```

I found QQuickWebEngineProfile, but couldn't found way to set it, and it was empty profile.

```
profile = QtWebEngine.QQuickWebEngineProfile("foo")
profile.isOffTheRecord() #True
```

How to set effective named QQuickWebEngineProfile to QQmlApplicationEngine?

Comment: I think you're getting confused, QQuickWebEngineProfile is not a profile for QQmlApplicationEngine but for WebEngineView (QWebEngineView for QML). What did you expect you want to control when setting a profile to QQmlApplicationEngine? I think you have a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Oh... thanks, I'm just in confusion. I want to use any string instead of "Default" for profile and cache when use load web page with QQmlApplicationEngine's (or QML's?) WebEngineView. (e.g. ~/.local/appname/QtWebEngine/Default)